# IDA does not show symbol information

Tags: ios, gdb, reverse-engineering, ida

I have been trying to reverse a `Mach-O executable arm` file and I'm able to debug it just fine in gdb for iOS, and the binary doesn't seem to be stripped as gdb shows me the function names etc.; however, when I pop the binary into IDA, I dont see any of these function names(and this is making the disassembly quite hard). IDA does show me the names of the functions that are imported, but other function names dont show up.

This has never happened before, IDA usually recognizes function names if gdb does in my experience.

Has something similar happened for anyone here? If so, how did you remedy the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDA does not support Dwarf debug info at the moment (in version 6.2), that could be it. I'd suggest dumping the symbols with `otool` or something to a text file and making a simple Python script to import them.